# KeyError when setting the index of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `port` and I'm trying to set its index as follows. However, I get the error `KeyError: 0` in the line `port = port.set_index(l)` and don't know why this is. Currently `port` has an Index of Strings.

`port` looks like this:

```
Date            ^GSPC       AAPL         IBM      dell        wmt                                                   
2013-10-29  1771.949951  71.290195  174.302136  13.86000  73.328899
2013-10-28  1762.109985  73.111495  169.736908  13.83000  73.405027
```

The code:

```
l = [0]*port.shape[0]
count = 0
for i,j in enumerate(l):
    l[i] = count
    count += 1 
port = port.set_index(l)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) sets the DataFrame index (row labels) using one or more existing columns, the `keys` is the column label or list of column labels / arrays.

I guess you want to set the index of the DataFrame to be `l`? You can set it by

```
port = port.set_index([l])
```

or simply

```
port.index = l
```